# Ghost foreach missing post context

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm trying to access the post published_at date inside a loop that's iterating over the authors of a post but it's not working

This is an example: the date outside of the foreach block is correct but inside the block it will default to the current date

```
{{date published_at format="D MMMM YYYY"}}
{{#foreach authors}}
  <time class="author--date">{{date published_at format="D MMMM YYYY"}}</time>   
{{/foreach}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghost uses Handlebars template syntax, and in your case `foreach` creates a new scope. So inside it you need to access parent scope to get `published_at` variable.

By prepending ../ to the property name, you can reference the parent scope. [Check docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context) for more info.

So in your case it should be:

```html
{{date published_at format="D MMMM YYYY"}}
{{#foreach authors}}
  <time class="author--date">{{date ../published_at format="D MMMM YYYY"}}</time>   
{{/foreach}}
```